# Unexpected response code 500 for my api link

Tags: android

i have a server side api method which accept Model class as a parameter

which does work  fine i have checked it but from android i am confused how to send a Model class as a parameter?

```
 public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText email, password;
    String   Email, Pass;
    Button loginbtn;
    String URL = "https://192.168.0.102/api/campaign/Logins";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        handleSSLHandshake();
        email =  findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        password =  findViewById(R.id.password);
        loginbtn = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Email = email.getText().toString();
                Pass = password.getText().toString();
                StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                // response
                                Log.d("Response", response);
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                // error
                                Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                            }
                        }
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                    {


                        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("email", Email);
                        params.put("password", Pass);

                        return params;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                        return headers;
                    }



                };
                queue.add(postRequest);
            }
        });
```

This is what i have tried i know the problem is from the server side can anyone help me what i am thinking is the problem or is there anything else ?

Comment: public IHttpActionResult Logins(User user)
        {
//My Code
}  Api Method

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a JSONObject with the post parameters as key-value pairs in the JSON Object. Here is the example for you:

```
JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
    postparams.put("keyX", "valueX")
    postparams.put("KEY", "Value")
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        url, postparams,
        new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //Success Callback
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Failure Callback
            }
        });
```

Comment: still the same error nothing changed can you tell me how can i send from body because with postman i am sending with  body

Comment: the above example sends JsonObject as body

Comment: but it doesnt call onresponse as well as onerrorresponse method just skip the methods no exception